# Prevent Safari on iOS from opening pop-ups in background

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, safari

I have a site that uses pop-ups for certain areas of the site (which have target="_blank"), and I have noticed that Safari on iOS devices tends to open these pop-ups in the background, while keeping focus on the current tab, and not switching to the pop-up when it opens.

Is there a way / workaround to prevent Safari acting like this and instead open them in foreground and focus on them when they open?

Thanks!

Comment: Try saving a reference to the window you open and call `focus()` on it. That said, you should try converting your popups to modals that open in the current window. Opening separate browser windows is outdated, annoying for your users and also likely to be blocked by many browsers.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.
I am actually using modals for things like registration and login on my site, but I can't use anything other than pop-ups for certain things like app authorization or social network logins - with which I encounter this problem.